# d3 tsv not working with django

Tags: javascript, python, django, d3.js

I know this question is asked multiple times, but my problem seems to be unique:

[image]

my django view:

```
def data(request):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get('epk'))
    occurrences = event.occurrences.all()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/tsv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="data.tsv"'

    response.write('date\tclose\n')
    for occ in occurrences:
        response.write('%s\t%s\n' % (occ.timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), occ.counter))

    return response
```

and js:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

    var x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var line = d3.line().x(function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
    }).y(function (d) {
        return y(d.close);
    });

    d3.tsv("{% url 'data' %}?epk={{ event.id }}", function (d) {
        d.date = parseTime(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
        return d;
    }, function (error, data) {

        console.log(data); // ----> the screenshot at the bottom

        if (error) throw error;

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.date;
        }));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.close;
        }));

        g.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 1 + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x)) // <---- error place
            .select(".domain")
            .remove();

        g.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .append("text")
            .attr("fill", "#000")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", "0.71em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Occurs");

        g.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
            .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .attr("d", line);
    });
</script>
```

content of tsv file I get from my django view is:

```
date    close
2017-02-12 14:07:14 1
2017-02-12 14:07:35 1
2017-02-12 17:12:14 1
2017-02-12 17:23:40 1
2017-02-12 17:51:52 1
2017-02-13 04:15:58 1
```

the worst part is that it is working on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Moyyawptt8lY0pLBDQDr?p=preview

but in my code, something is wrong. I just dont know where to debug, since the error message is so horribly unclear.

can someone please help me out? it would be the greatest help to humanity!

this is the screenshot from the `console.log(data);`

[image]